# How do GPS receivers map out directions?

Tags: routing

Although I've never really dug into it, I've always assumed mapping out directions in a GPS unit is done with [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a) or [Fibonacci-heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) at a higher level and [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for smaller graphs. Are there any other algorithms being used that aren't immediately obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack Overflow has a detailed response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430142/what-algorithms-compute-directions-from-point-a-to-point-b-on-a-map) to a similar question, I won't try to reproduce it here. For GPS receivers without internet access, likely all major routes are precomputed, and then only supplemented for the end-nodes when heading off freeways. The Google blog [has some background](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/11/road-to-better-path-finding.html) on their 'draggable directions', but alas no algorithmic meat.